# Jetty Session Clustering Using XML

Tags: java, database, session, jetty-9

Im trying to configure jetty session clustering using database. Is there a way to change the database name. I dont want to use the default name "session". Also i want to change the table name for both sessionidtable and sessiontable but I am having trouble setting up the configuration using xml. Here my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">


  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- Configure a SessionIdManager                                          -->
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <Set name="sessionIdManager">
    <New id="idMgr" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionIdManager">
      <Arg>
        <Ref refid="Server"/>
      </Arg>
      <Set name="workerName"><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.workerName" default="node1"/></Set>
      <Set name="scavengeInterval"><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.scavenge" default="1800"/></Set>

      <!-- ===================================================================== -->
      <!-- Uncomment either the datasource or driver setup and configure         -->
      <!-- ===================================================================== -->

      <!--
          <Set name="DatasourceName"><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.datasource" default="javax.sql.DataSource/default"/></Set>
          <Call name="setDriverInfo">
          <Arg><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.driverClass"/></Arg>
          <Arg><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.connectionURL"/></Arg>
        </Call>
      -->

    </New>
  </Set>

  <New id="idTableSchema " class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionTableSchema">
    <Set name="setTableName">mysession</Set>
  </New>

</Configure>
```

But in the logs it says that :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionTableSchema
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:754)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1243)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
        ... 7 more

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Set name="sessionTableSchema">
  <New id="tableSchema" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionIdManager$SessionTableSchema">
    <Set name="tableName">mysession</Set>
  </New>
</set>
```

It does say org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionTableSchema in the jetty documentation but the links are broken.  The above code is the only way I could get it to work and matches the API documentation.  The id table is handled very similarly.

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/JDBCSessionIdManager.html